# Definition of robotics manipulator?

Tags: manipulator, first-robotics

I'm new to robotics, I don't understand the way wikipedia defines robotics manipulator. If there is no any direct contact how could the robot move things within his work envelope.

> In robotics a manipulator is a device used to manipulate materials
>   without direct contact

source [robotics manipulator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manipulator_(device))

Comment: direct contact between what and what? .... the article appears to be poorly worded

Comment: That is what I want to know.

Comment: what does the next sentence in the article mean to you?

Comment: I think robots can do tasks that humans can't like removing electrons in an atom(radioactive).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original manipulators referred to in that article were through-the-wall pantographs which moved radioactive materials without the human operator having direct contact with those materials.  The end effectors of those manipulators did have direct contact with the materials - just not the human.  Although the article is not specific about this, it seems they carry that concept forward for programmable manipulators - that the person doing (or supervising) the task does not engage the product directly.